# aux output with hdmi as video

Tags: audio, hdmi

I am new to the Pi, loving it.

Just started using HDMI instead of composite pal ( obvious reasons) but I want to keep sound going through AUX so I can play with better speakers. I looked around but very hard to find much information.

Any suggestions would be great, sound was working previously but not any more :( 
I am running RetroPi, basically Raspbian Model b raspberry pi

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use

```
sudo amixer cset numid=3 <output>
```

in the terminal with `<output>` replaced by one of the following numbers for which output you want

0=auto

1=Audio Jack

2=hdmi

Comment: will give it a shot when I try again tommorow , have found a few other changes I could make to config, 
hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1 may work??

browsing through here was good, maybe useful for other beginners elinux.org/RPiconfig


thank you will try and inform back tommorow hopefuly

Answer (score 2):

amixer command has no effect for me (Raspberry PI Modell B Rev 2.0, 512MB with Raspbian wheezy).

I have to set **hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1** in **/boot/config.txt** file and I have to reboot.

Source : http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video_mode_options

```
echo '# Pretends all audio formats are unsupported by display. This means ALSA will default to analogue.' | sudo tee --append /boot/config.txt 
echo 'hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1' | sudo tee --append /boot/config.txt
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Start `raspi-config` from the terminal/CLI:

   ```bsh
   sudo raspi-config
   ```
2. select system options
3. select audio
4. select '1 headphones'
5. select "Finish" by pressing the right arrow key twice and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>